# GTK 3 transparent label with text placed over image

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtk3

i need to create GTK GUI with image and transparent label (darker) that is placed over the image. The first problem is overlapping. I tried Gtk::Table and Gtk::Fixed container but it behaves strangely. The second problem is transparency. I would like to use CSS styles or transparent background image. Is there anybody who can help me posting some sources or examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass **GtkWidget**, or **GtkDrawingArea** since I think it will be faster than the altenatives. But you could use **GtkOverlay**, plus **GtkImage** and **GtkLabel** to acomplish what you're looking for.
**gtk3-demo** app that comes with Gtk+-3.0 give some examples of how to use **GtkOverlay**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give a look to clutter-gtk ? You can do [nice things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeV4EOee3CI) with it.